# How can I see the page and controller in developer mode using Chrome?

Tags: visualforce

I have developer mode on for my user account; however, I cannot see the content of the page or the page controller.  I can see the view state but nothing else. I am using Chrome version 44.0.2403.125 m (64-bit).

I can see everything using IE or Firefox but I would rather do all of my development in Chrome (certainly not IE if possible).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Although this is not the answer that you are looking for, but if you want to do the development in the browser and not use an IDE, then https://www.aside.io/ is also a very good option.

Comment: aside.io is the way to go!

Answer (score 2):

See if you have the parameter "core.apexpages.devmode.url=1" in the url.
If yes then remove it.

Comment: Actually, it is a legitimate potential answer to the question. There is a chance that the asker does have that in the URL, and if that is the case, then this would be a good answer.
I hope you're not letting your permissions in this group go to your head... I've seen a few of these paragraphs posted by you inappropriately. And from someone whose answers I think are not as high quality as most, though certainly high quantity...